# "Posts matching query does not exist." error while navigating to "admin page" in django?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am learning Django and working on making a simple blog website. Now the whole project is working fine but whenever I navigate to the admin panel it shows the error "Posts matching query does not exist.".

Let me know which part of the code you want to see(i'm confused which file has the error)

error :

```
Environment:
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin

Django Version: 2.0.5
Python Version: 3.6.5
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'posts']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']

  Traceback:

File "C:\Users\Fruity_Dude\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
  packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)
File "C:\Users\Fruity_Dude\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
  packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, 
  request)
File "C:\Users\Fruity_Dude\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
  packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, 
  **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Fruity_Dude\Projects\Django\devflow\posts\views.py" in 
  post_details
  10.   posts = Posts.objects.get(slug=slug)
File "C:\Users\Fruity_Dude\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
  packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in manager_method
  82.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, 
  **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Fruity_Dude\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
  packages\django\db\models\query.py" in get
  403.                 self.model._meta.object_name
Exception Type: DoesNotExist at /admin
Exception Value: Posts matching query does not exist.
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'posts'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.posts, name='home'),
    path('<slug:slug>', views.post_details, name='detail'),
]
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Posts
from django.http import HttpResponse

def posts(request):
    posts = Posts.objects.all().order_by('date')
    return render(request, 'posts/posts.html', {'posts': posts})

def post_details(request, slug):
    posts = Posts.objects.get(slug=slug)
    return render(request, 'posts/post_details.html', {'posts': posts})
```

main **urls.py**:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from . import views
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls), #for admin
    path('', include('posts.urls')),
    path('about/', views.about, name='about'), #for about
    path('contact/', views.contact, name='contact'), #for contact
    path('support/', views.support, name='support'), #for support
    path('donate/', views.donate, name='donate') #for donate
]

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: You need to show your urls.py. Your admin path is being captured by the post_details view

Comment: And next time, please click that "switch to copy and paste view" and post the error text, rather than posting a screenshot.

Comment: got it, thanks. i'm going to edit the post! @DanielRoseman

Comment: No it is your main URLs you need to show.

Comment: ohh main urls! sorry.doing.

Comment: Are you sure that is the exact file? What you have posted here would work fine.

Comment: you sure you ran makemigrations and migrate?

Comment: @Mattias please don't randomly suggest that, it has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: I have uploaded the whole project to GitHub (https://github.com/abhayaman669/devflow) you can see if you want @DanielRoseman.

Comment: @mattias that's all fine(migration)

Comment: @mattiias, I was searching for the solution for the error and finally after changing the `path('<slug:slug>', views.post_details, name='detail'),`  to `url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.post_details, name='detail'),` its working fine. now its not showing any error. So, what was the error actually. anyways thanks for helping :D

Comment: the edited code is from the app urls.py file :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seem to be that you are running

```
posts = Posts.objects.get(slug=slug)
```

and your url catches

```
path('<slug:slug>', views.post_details, name='detail')
```

For instance when you do `http://domain:port/a-post/` what will be matched in argument `slug` is `'a-post/'` (notice the trailing `/`)

You wrote in a comment that

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.post_details, name='detail')
```

fixed the issue. That is probably because the trailing `/` is now not included in the resulting `slug` variable.

The error is raised by `Posts.objects.get(slug=slug)` since the `.get`-method requires one and only one row to be matched. ([see django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-a-single-object-with-get))

To avoid that problem, I see two solutions you should implement.

1. Change the match to `path('<slug:slug>/', views.post_details, name='detail')`, i.e. added a `/`.
2. Use the filter-method.

For example:

```
posts = Posts.objects.filter(slug=slug).all()  # all() to make django perform the sql select command and return list
if not posts:
    # handle error case, either return 404 or redirect somewhere. 
elif len(posts) > 1:
    # handle the weird case when there was more than one matching post
post = posts[0]
# render using post instead of posts, since it is only one post
```

Comment: ya, that can be the problem. so, what else can I do in the place of `Posts.objects.get(slug=slug)`.

Comment: I added some suggestions